# Cannot access node server on Mac from different device on local network

Tags: node.js, macos, osx-mavericks

I'm running node server on my Mac with OS X 10.9.Here is the code

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');

console.log('Server running at http://192.168.1.120:3000/');
```

I can use Safari on my mac to access server at `http://192.168.1.120:3000/`. But when I access the server with my iPhone, it failed.
My Mac's firewall is off and my iPhone is at the same WiFi with Mac.

Comment: Is the firewall on your mac turned on? Is the iPhone really using WiFi and not 3G?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Firewall is off and iPhone is using WiFi.

Comment: Are you sure your iPhone sees your Mac in your network? You can use apps like [Fing](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8) to check this, to ping your Mac.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros I use Fing find that iPhone can't see Mac in local network. It seems that the problem is in OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Answering due to low reputation. I'm not sure if this addresses the issue you have.

First, I noticed the address in the listen function and what's printing out to the console are different. Second, if the Node is running on your computer locally, you would want to connect to your computer's IP, not the one provided by the Node server. I believe Mac has an `ifconfig` command for the terminal. This should give you back the computer's IP on your network.

I copied your code and removed the '0.0.0.0' from the `listen` function. I was then able to spin up the server and connect to it on my phone (using the computer's IP). Granted, this was on a MacBook running Arch and using a Note III to connect.

Hope this helps!